# Simple relation between two tables

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, key, one-to-many

I started using NHibernate today, but I cannot figure out how I setup a simple relation between two tables. I don't really know what it's called, it could be one-to-many or foreign key relation (I'm not that into database design and the terms used), but here's a very simple example.

I have a table Product with attributes Id (PK), ProductName and CategoryId. Then I have a table Categories with attributes Id (PK) and CategoryName.

I created these classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }  
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }  

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }  

    public virtual string CategoryName  
    {  
        get { return this.Category == null ? String.Empty : this.Category.CategoryName; } 
    }
}

public class Category  
{  
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, I simply want the Product to store to which category it belongs (via the CategoryId attribute which points to an Id in the Categories table). I **don't** need the Category class to hold a list of related Products, if that makes it any simpler.

To make it even more clear what I'm after, this is the SQL that I'm expecting:

```
SELECT Products.*, Categories.*
FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryId = Categories.Id
```

at least that's what I think it should be (again, I'm not that good at database design or queries).

I can't figure out which kind of mapping I need for this. I suppose I need to map it in the Product.hbm.xml file. But do I map the CategoryId as well? And how do I map the Category property?

It seems like I would need a 'one-to-many' relation since I have ONE category per product (or is this reasoning backward?) but it seems like there is no one-to-many mapping...

Thanks for any help!

**Addition:**

I tried to add the many-to-one relation in the Person mapping, but I keep getting an exception saying "Creating proxy failed", and in the inner exception "Ambiguous match found".

I should maybe mention I am using an old version of NHibernate (1.2 I think) because that is the only one I got running with MS Access due to it not finding the JetDriver in newer versions.

I've put the mapping files, classes, and code where the error occurs in screenshots because I can't figure out how to post XML code here... It keeps reading it as html tags and skipping half of it. Anyway.

The mappings:
http://www.nickthissen.nl/Images/tmp7B5A.png

The classes:
http://www.nickthissen.nl/Images/tmpF809.png

The loading code where the error occurs:
http://www.nickthissen.nl/Images/tmp46B6.png
(As I said, the inner exception says "Ambiguous match found".

(Product in my example has been replaced by Person)

The Person and Category classes inherit Entity which is an abstract base class and defines the Id, Deleted, CreatedTime and UpdatedTime properties. 
The code where the error occurs is in a generic 'manager' class (type parameter TEntity which must inherit Entity). It is simply supposed to load all entities with the Deleted attribute false. In this case, TEntity is 'Person'.

It works fine if I leave out the many-to-one Category mapping in the Person mapping, but then obviously the Category property is always null.

Oh yeah, sorry about the mix between C# and VB, the C# code is in a generic framework I use for multiple projects while the VB part is the actual implementation of that framework on my website and I just happened to use VB for that.

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Product class only needs to contain a Category object, you don't need a CategoryId property. Then in your Product mapping you need to have this entry

```
<many-to-one name="Category" column="CategoryId" />
```

**UPDATE**:
Your mappings appear to be missing the fully qualified name of the mapped class in the  tag. See http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class

**UPDATE 2**:

See if this helps you [NHibernate 1.2 in a .NET 4.0 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301157/nhibernate-1-2-in-a-net-4-0-solution/3333843#3333843)

Comment: I tried this, but I keep getting an exception saying "Creating proxy failed", and in the inner exception "Ambiguous match found". I'd like to show you the code where it occurs and the mapping but it seems I cannot do any of that in a comment (I'm new to this site)... How am I supposed to show you what I tried if I can't show any code / xml mappings?

Comment: I added everything to my question at the top, see there.

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference. I replace name="Person" with name="NhibernateWebTest.Database.Person" (and same for category) but the behavior remains the same. I can view and edit categories, but I cannot view the persons because it gives me the same error when it tries to load them.

Comment: @Nick Thissen, your entities appear to be in a different assembly (I'm assuming so, since you're using VB in your entities, but C# in your loader class). That means you also need to supply the assembly name like this name="NhibernateWebTest.Database.Person, NhibernateWebTest" or whatever the assembly actually is

Comment: Still doesn't work :( 
Let me explain the project setup. I've got a project DatabaseFramework (C#), which contains the Entity baseclass and the EntityManager class (which has the Load method it is throwing the exception in). Then, I have another project, NHibernateWebTest (VB), which contains the Person and Category classes (which inherit DatabaseFramework.Entity, from the other project), and which contains the mapping files. Let me repeat that: the mapping files and the entity classes are in the NHibernateWebTest project, while the Entity base and loading method are in another project.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the solution explorer. Hope this clears things up. I'm not sure which assembly to use in the class declaration (in the mappings), since the actual classes are in one project, but their base classes are in another. Screenshot: http://www.nickthissen.nl/Images/tmp3E0.jpg

Comment: @Nick Thissen, total shot in the dark, but are you including your mapping files as Embedded Resources?

Comment: Yes. I should mention again that without your extra many-to-one mapping, everything works fine, except that the Category property (of Person) obviously remains null. I can add/edit/remove categories as well as persons just fine, so the mappings should be fine. It's only your extra many-to-one mapping that causes this problem.

Comment: @Nick Thissen, Right, ok well as a last ditch resort you can try specifying the class property in the many to one like so <many-to-one name="Category" column="CategoryId" class="NHibernate.Database.Category, NHibernateWebTest" />

Comment: Hey, something different... I dunno if that's a good thing though. Now it throws an exception when adding the current assembly to the Configuration object. It says "Could not load type 'NHibernate.Database.Category' from assembly 'NHibernateWebTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.". I can't find any typos, and Category is definitely in the NHibernate.Database namespace. I dunno why it can't load it... I did not define any additional constructors (in Category nor in Entity) so it should have an accessible parameterless constructor as well. Any further idea's?

Comment: Again, I am using an older version of NHibernate (1.2.1 I think) because I cannot get v2 or v3 to work with MS Access due to it not finding the JetDriver DLL. This might be related...? If you have any idea how to get v3 to work with Access correctly I'd be happy to use v3 but I need Access so I can't at the moment...

Comment: Ok (sorry for triple post), I ran it again without changing anything, and now it says "Duplicate class/entity mapping Category". Huh?

Comment: @Nick Thissen, that should probably be NHibernateWebTest.Database.Category in your mapping, rather than NHiberante.Database.Category. BTW make sure that the class names are correct with namespaces and that the assembly is the right one

Comment: Ugh yes, you're right. I even double checked it... Anyway, back to square one. Now the original exception is back again. It seems to make no difference whether I specify the assembly + complete namespace or just leave them out altogether (I guess NHibernate is smart enough to figure them out as long as no duplicate names exist in different namespaces or something). So yeah... It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks, switching to .NET 3.5 seemed to "solve" my current issue. Now I have another problem though. Perhaps I should have created a new thread for this but it might be related, and you already know the structure of my projects etc so it's easier to keep it in here I think. I added my next question as another answer (as I am also answering my first question there it seemed appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

The 'Ambiguous match found' exception was caused by the project targeting .NET Framework 4, which does not seem to be compatible with NHibernate 1.2.1. I switched to 3.5 and that seems to solve that particular issue.

Now on to the next. As you can see, the Person class has a CategoryName property that should return the name of the current Category object, or an empty string if the category happens to be null. This is so I can databind a collection of Person objects to a grid, specifying 'CategoryName' as a property to bind a column to.

Apparently this does not work with NHibernate. Whenever I try to databind my collection of persons, I get this exception:

```
"Property accessor 'CategoryName' on object 'NHibernateWebTest.Database.Person' threw the following exception:'Could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed.'"
```

This occurs on the 'DataBind' method call in this code:

```
        public virtual void LoadGrid()
        {
            if (this.Grid == null) return;
```

```
        this.Grid.DataSource = this.Manager.Load();
        this.Grid.DataBind();
    }
```

(This is an ASP.NET project and 'Grid' is a GridView)

'this.Manager' returns an existing instance of NHibernateEntityManager, and I've already shown its Load method before, it contains this:

```
        public virtual EntityCollection Load()
        {
            using (ISession session = this.GetSession())
            {
                var entities = session
                                .CreateCriteria(typeof (TEntity))
                                .Add(Expression.Eq("Deleted", false))
                                .List();
                return new EntityCollection(entities);
            }
        }
```

(THere's some generic type parameters in there but this website seems to hide them (due to the html like tags I guess)... Sorry about that).

This may have something to do with NHibernate itself, as I said I'm completely new to this. When I call my Load method I would expect it to return an EntityCollection(Of Person) with all its properties already set. It seems I have to keep the ISession open while I am databinding for some reason..? That seems a little strange...
Can I get around this? Can I make my Load method simply return a collection of persons already fully loaded, so that I can access CategoryName whenever I want?

Wait... Is this lazy loading perhaps?

Comment: start a new question and I'll post the solution for you, also feel free to mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Ok, I will. I didn't mark it as accepted yet because well... It isn't solved yet :p I can't verify that your solution (the many-to-one solution) does what I want, but you seem reasonably confident so ok :)

Comment: I started a new question, see here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685671/many-to-one-relation-exception-due-to-closed-session-after-loading