# Many-to-one relation exception due to closed session after loading

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, session

I am using NHibernate (version 1.2.1) for the first time so I wrote a simple test application (an ASP.NET project) that uses it. In my database I have two tables: Persons and Categories. Each person gets one category, seems easy enough.

```
| Persons      |      | Categories   |
|--------------|      |--------------|
| Id (PK)      |      | Id (PK)      |
| Firstname    |      | CategoryName |
| Lastname     |      | CreatedTime  |
| CategoryId   |      | UpdatedTime  |
| CreatedTime  |      | Deleted      |
| UpdatedTime  |
| Deleted      |
```

The Id, CreatedTime, UpdatedTime and Deleted attributes are a convention I use in all my tables, so I have tried to bring this fact into an additional abstraction layer. I have a project DatabaseFramework which has three important classes:

- Entity: an abstract class that defines these four properties. All 'entity objects' (in this case Person and Category) must inherit Entity.
- IEntityManager: a generic interface (type parameter as Entity) that defines methods like Load, Insert, Update, etc.
- NHibernateEntityManager: an implementation of this interface using NHibernate to do the loading, saving, etc.

Now, the Person and Category classes are straightforward, they just define the attributes of the tables of course (keeping in mind that four of them are in the base Entity class).
Since the Persons table is related to the Categories table via the CategoryId attribute, the Person class has a Category property that holds the related category. However, in my webpage, I will also need the name of this category (CategoryName), for databinding purposes for example. So I created an additional property CategoryName that returns the CategoryName property of the current Category property, or an empty string if the Category is null:

```
Namespace Database
    Public Class Person
        Inherits DatabaseFramework.Entity
```

```
    Public Overridable Property Firstname As String
    Public Overridable Property Lastname As String
    Public Overridable Property Category As Category

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property CategoryName As String
        Get
            Return If(Me.Category Is Nothing, _
                      String.Empty, _
                      Me.Category.CategoryName)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

End Namespace

I am mapping the Person class using this mapping file. The many-to-one relation was suggested by Yads in another thread:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<property name="CreatedTime" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
<property name="UpdatedTime" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
<property name="Deleted" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />

<property name="Firstname" type="String" />
<property name="Lastname" type="String" />
<many-to-one name="Category" column="CategoryId" class="NHibernateWebTest.Database.Category, NHibernateWebTest" />
```

(I can't get it to show the root node, this forum hides it, I don't know how to escape the html-like tags...)

The final important detail is the Load method of the NHibernateEntityManager implementation. (This is in C# as it's in a different project, sorry about that).
I simply open a new ISession (ISessionFactory.OpenSession) in the GetSession method and then use that to fill an EntityCollection(Of TEntity) which is just a collection inheriting System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T).

```
        public virtual EntityCollection< TEntity > Load()
        {
            using (ISession session = this.GetSession())
            {
                var entities = session
                                .CreateCriteria(typeof (TEntity))
                                .Add(Expression.Eq("Deleted", false))
                                .List< TEntity >();
                return new EntityCollection< TEntity >(entities);
            }
        }
```

(Again, I can't get it to format the code correctly, it hides the generic type parameters, probably because it reads the angled symbols as a HTML tag..? If you know how to let me do that, let me know!)

Now, the idea of this Load method is that I get a fully functional collection of Persons, all their properties set to the correct values (including the Category property, and thus, the CategoryName property should return the correct name).
However, it seems that is not the case. When I try to data-bind the result of this Load method to a GridView in ASP.NET, it tells me this:

```
Property accessor 'CategoryName' on object 'NHibernateWebTest.Database.Person' threw the following exception:'Could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed.'
```

The exception occurs on the DataBind method call here:

```
        public virtual void LoadGrid()
        {
            if (this.Grid == null) return;
```

```
        this.Grid.DataSource = this.Manager.Load();
        this.Grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Well, of course the session is closed, I closed it via the using block. Isn't that the correct approach, should I keep the session open? And for how long? Can I close it after the DataBind method has been run?

In each case, I'd really like my Load method to just return a functional collection of items. It seems to me that it is now only getting the Category when it is required (eg, when the GridView wants to read the CategoryName, which wants to read the Category property), but at that time the session is closed. Is that reasoning correct?

How do I stop this behavior? Or shouldn't I? And what should I do otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting lazy loading = false in your mapping will solve the error. It would be a better practice though to tell NHibernate in your load query that you want to fetch the child collection of categories eagerly.

For a criteia query something like .SetFetchMode("Categories", FetchMode.Eager) should work.

Here is a [link](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/02/CombatingTheSelectN1ProblemInNHibernate.aspx) that gives some insight into the so called "n + 1" problem, how lazy loading relates to it, and how NHibernate is meant to be used.

HTH,
Berryl

something like this:

```
           var entities = session
                            .CreateCriteria<TEntity>()
                            .SetFetchMode("Categories", FetchMode.Eager)
                            .Add(Expression.Eq("Deleted", false))
                            .List< TEntity >();
```

Comment: Thanks. The SetFetchMode is not an option for me since I'm using my generic Manager class (which should work for any Entity). I was able to disable lazy loading for the moment (so that I could finally see that the mapping actually worked) but I understand it is not an ideal solution. I will look into it more.

Comment: @Nick. Just to be clear, that eager fetch mode modifies your Load query, not any mappings. Try the modified query at the end of my answer, put lazy load back to true (the default), and see if it works for you. Cheers

Comment: Yes, I got that, but my Manager class is generic and takes an Entity type parameter. The Load method should work for any Entity, and in your code I have to specify that I want the Categories property to be 'eagerly fetched'. I cannot know that every Entity will have a Categories property (they don't) so that won't work. Unless I add additional logic in Entity that I can use to determine if there are properties to fill in this way. In other words, your code works only when TEntity = Person, but will fail for any other entity that does not have a Categories property.

Comment: Ah, ok. That sounds a overly generic to be very useful in a lot of situations, this being one of them, but you know your requirements way better than I do. Assuming the Manager is a data access manager (like a Dao or Repository), you could make it satisfy a query spec. Here are some [ideas for doing](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/repository-or-dao-dao.html) that Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your entity is lazy loaded. The query only gets the items that it currently needs. So in your case it gets the Person object. Then when you access any linked entities, it fires off another query. It uses proxy objects for this that know about the Session that was used. You are only keeping the Session open for the Load and then you're closing it.

This is actually bad practice in the NHibernate world. You want to keep the session alive for a period known as a [unit of work](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx). This gives you a lot of benefits, like caching and lazy loading. Consequently you can disable lazy loading it should work. Although I'd recommend modifying your loader class if at all possiblem

Comment: Thanks. Disabling lazy loading made it work, but I understand that that's not an ideal solution. I'll take a look at modifying my manager class, that shouldn't be too hard since the place where I'm loading the grid (grid.DataBind) is in the same framework and is the one creating the Manager instance. I'd just have to stop creating new sessions for every load/insert/update/etc and see how I can divide that bit better. Thanks! I'd like to mark your solution as the answer as well but apparently only 1 post can be marked as such... Sorry.